# jquery toggle sets property as display : table instead of block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across the following situation while playing with some code where toggle on a table tag sets the attribute style as "display: table" instead of "display: block". ( You would need to use developer tools like firebug to see this behavior). As per my understanding toggle only sets the display as 'none' or 'block'.

Here's the code :

```
<button class="read">Toggle Table</button>
<table class="displayReviews"></table>
<br>
<button class="write">Toggle Form</button>
    <form class="writeForm">Form</form>

<script>
$('button').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr("class") == "read")
   {
       $(".displayReviews").toggle();
   }
   else if($(this).attr("class") == "write")
   {
       $(".writeForm").toggle();
   }    
});
</script>

<style>
.writeForm
{
    display:none;    
}

.displayReviews
{
   display:none;    
}
</style>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thL7Lyff/

Could anybody help me understand why it happens ? Thanks In advance.

Comment: from the jquery docs: "The display property is saved and restored as needed." http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ if it starts as table, it will be restored as table.

Comment: Agreed. But if that's the case then every html control should behave that way. What is so different about table tag.

Comment: there are many different display properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display there would be all sorts of unexpected bugs if jquery set all things to `block` rather than the initial style.

Comment: you use `displayReviews` class in a table, where table has default display property to display:table,Jquery toggle change default property to none and then default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('button').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr("class") == "read")
   {

     if($(".displayReviews").css("display") == "none"){
       $(".displayReviews").css("display", "block");
     } else {
      $(".displayReviews").css("display", "none");
     }

   }
   else if($(this).attr("class") == "write")
   {
       $(".writeForm").toggle();
   }    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know how it could be fixed. The question is related to why it behaves that way.